# Why d is not equal to 1.0?

Tags: c

Hello I have a C question, I hope someone explains this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double d = 0.;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        d += .10;

    if (d == 1.)
        printf("d is 1.\n");
    else
        printf("d is not 1.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer is d is not 1.

But shouldn't d be 10? But when I debug the code it is not always increasing by 0.1. It sometimes increases by 0.099999999998 or so.

Comment: Because 10 * 0.1 is hardly ever 1. It is in math, but not with floating point arithmetic, since 0.1 is not exactly representable.

Comment: `0.1 == 0.099999999` is `true` (if the compiler can't evaluate them at arbitrary precision, for two `float*`). Effectively, they're the same number under the hood, neither of which exactly represents what is shown.